# Is it possible to set a different frontend- and backend-language?

Tags: localization, language

my WordPress site is currently set to "English". I like the back-end to be completely in English, so it is easier to follow tutorial instructions etc. However, the front-end must be in German due to different reasons.

For instance, in need to have `lang="de-DE"` in the HTML-header for some plugin to work correctly.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the site language to whatever you wish in the `Settings > General > Site Language`.

After that, you can head over to your profile and choose a language for the back-end. To do so, head over to `Users > Your Profile > Language` and change it to English.

However, there is an issue with Admin-Ajax requests. If you set the back-end language to English, the Ajax requests will be in English too.

Comment: Thank you, that actually worked! Is it possible that this is only available since the last update 4.8.1? I didn't see this option before the update...

Comment: You're welcome. It's been around for a while, but yes it didn't exist in some older versions.